# command not found

Tags: debian, update

I use Debian and try to run update-rc.d sphinx defaults, buts it's shows:

```
update-rc.d command not found
```

Script sphinx already exists.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Can I ask what version of Debian you are running?

Comment: Are you `sudo`ing, or logged in as root?  You should have `/usr/sbin` in your `$PATH` -- `/usr/sbin/update-rc.d`

Answer (score 5):

`sudo update-rc.d`

or

`sudo /usr/sbin/update-rc.d`

If the second one works but the first one doesn't, something is wrong with your $PATH variables.